# import dart:html throws error when build on android emulator, but I need html

Tags: flutter, dart-html, dart-define

My flutter app uses a maps API key as below.

create_script_element.dart

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'current_flavour.dart';

void createScriptElement() {
  ScriptElement script = ScriptElement();

  script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${currentFlavor()}&language=en&libraries=drawing&callback=Function.prototype";
  script.id = "super-script";

  document.head?.append(script);
}
```

Another file 'current_flavour.dart' has the keys

```
const String flavorDev = "dev-key";
const String flavorProd = "prod-key";

String currentFlavor() {
  final flavor = const String.fromEnvironment("flavor", defaultValue: "dev");
  if (flavor == "prod") {
    return flavorProd;
  }

  return flavorDev;
}
```

This app is running perfectly as web app,

```
flutter run -d chrome --dart-define=flavor="prod"
```

but when I run on android emulator,

```
flutter run -d emulator-5554 --dart-define=flavor="prod"
```

it fails because of importing html. How should I proceed to run it on all platforms?

Comment: can you try with [html](https://pub.dev/packages/html) or [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html)

Comment: check https://dart.dev/libraries/dart-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dart:html is not designed for mobile platforms, you can use [Universal html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) instead or you can use conditional import depending on the cross platform.

Comment: universal_html solved my problem. conditional import did not work here there was an error during compilation for line ScriptElement script = ScriptElement();